# How do you share files between projects in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I know this has been asked before, but no good answers were given, and perhaps recent changes in TypeScript will provide a new solution.

[See this screenshot of Visual Studio. sharedMessage is stored in one project and linked to the other.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdYUk.png)

All I want to do is share sharedMessage.ts between the server and the client, but there seems to be a fundamental break between client and server loading modules.  The server uses export modules, while the client uses namespaces.  Obviously I'm missing something, but a day of googling has not provided me an answer that doesn't require installing and learning one or two (or more) third-party tools.

Can anybody give me a clue? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post links to screenshots of your code. Post them in the question itself.

Comment: Okay, but the code wasn't as important as showing everything and how it was organized.

Answer (score 1):

> The server uses export modules, while the client uses namespaces

Use modules *everywhere*. Preferable `commonjs`

- Quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html
- For a sample see how alm.tools is built http://alm.tools/

Comment: I attempted that, but kept ending up with "require" or "system" or whatever loader-specific keyword was being used in the .js files, which cannot be interpreted.

For example, the top of one of the javascript files ends up compiling to:

**var sharedMessage_1 = require("./../sharedMessage");**...

which results in error "JavaScript runtime error: 'require' is undefined"

Comment: if you bundled it with webpack (as shown in the quickstart) it should work

Comment: I was hoping for a non-third-party solution.  This just seems like something that should be handled natively. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my goal is unattainable without using a third-party tool.  The problem boils down to the server needs the first line of sharedMessage.ts to be

```
export class sharedMessage
```

while the client code needs to be just

```
class sharedMessage
```

Because I'm using visual studio, I navigated to project properties -> Build Events tab and added a prebuild.bat file to the Pre-Build text box.  In that batch file I simply put in

```
copy P:\TypeScript\Test\NodeJsMessage\sharedMessage.ts P:\TypeScript\Test\NodeJsMessage\NodeJsMessageClient\sharedMessage.ts /Y
p:\util\fnr.exe --cl --dir "P:\TypeScript\Test\NodeJsMessage\NodeJsMessageClient" --fileMask "sharedMessage.ts" --find "export class" --replace "//this file is generated automatically -- do not edit\nclass"
```

fnr.exe is a third-party "find and replace" tool. I simply replaced "export class" with just "class".  Now, before each build, any changes to the server sharedMessage.ts file are copied to the client project and "export" is removed.

I will have to add two lines to this batch file for every file I want to share between projects.  I guess this solution will have to be good enough for now.

Comment: You just built a "third party tool !" :)  Believe me, I went through this before, go with @basarat suggestion to use modules *everywhere*.  Also with ES6/2015, modules become the norm.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. I've spent the last week learning TypeScript, and every other forum question's answer seems to start with "npm install".  I'm sure I will look back and consider this whole question silly.